# How do I make my boot.log more verbose?

Tags: rhel, boot, logs

I am trying to resolve an issue about our /etc/resolv.conf getting reset to old values or getting empty. I see a function defined in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/network-functions that could be causing this. This behaviour is not consistent which is making it hard to debug. At this point, I would like to know different scenarios this function is being called during the boot time. So, is there a way I can make the boot.log more 'verbose' ? Are their different logging levels for boot.log? If yes, how can I set/change it?  At the moment /var/log/boot.log gives only so much details:

```
Starting mcelog daemon
Starting sshd:                             OK                                
Starting MySQL... SUCCESS!
 Starting sendmail:                             OK                                
Starting sm-client:                             OK                                
Starting abrt daemon:                             OK                                
Starting atd:                             OK  
.
.
.
```

The server is an RHEL 6.5

Answer (score 2):

You can modify in the file /etc/sysconfig/init , the field BOOTUP

Like :

```
BOOTUP=verbose
```

It should work at the next reboot.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. It did made the boot.log a little more verbose, but not verbose enough for my issue. Do we have different logging levels? like INFO, DEBUG..etc?